# PhpStorm bug when run a theme

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

When I run a theme on PhpStorm, the screen goes completely black every few seconds and then clears up in less than .6 seconds, but this cycle continues, but when I use the theme itself, it's perfectly fine.

I don't have explanation about this.

Comment: Details please!!! 1) What IDE version you have got there 2) OS used 3) Theme used 4) As I understand it works fine with any of the bundled themes? 5) By the way -- by "Theme" you mean the actual GUI theme or Syntax Highlighting colors (Color Scheme)? Some people use "theme" for both of them...

Comment: first must to say tanks for your helping, 1) 2022.3;2)ventura 13.2; 3) all theme (one dark pro, metal and....)yes bad working on all theme (just do well on default theme) (sorry if me English is not good im IRANian )

Comment: *"1) 2022.3;2)ventura 13.2"* At first look this could be https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JBR-4959/macOS-Ventura-Screen-flickering-after-OS-update-when-IDE-is-full-screen try the workaround with disabling the Metal rendering: _"For that, add the following string into `Help | Edit Custom VM Options`:  `-Dsun.java2d.metal=false` and restart the IDE"_

Comment: I added "-Dsun.java2d.metal=false" but still the problem is not fixed

Comment: In such a case please contact JetBrains Support directly -- just use `Help | Contact Support...` from the IDE itself; there you can privately provide all required information (like your `idea.log` etc.)

Comment: if they known im iranian blocking me

Comment: Use proxy. There is no need to provide your JetBrains account there AFAIK. You could be a person who wants to buy the product and currently evaluating it. Sorry, no better suggestions from me than checking tickets at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/JBR and look for the similar description/issue. That's how I found that ticket. Perhaps I have just looked at the wrong one...

Comment: can you help me for write a text ?

Comment: Use whatever you have used here already. Also mention your OS and IDE version.